# Excluding some ActiveRecord properties from xml rendering in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an ActiveRecord model that I would like to convert to xml, but I do not want all the properties rendered in xml. Is there a parameter I can pass into the render method to keep a property from being rendered in xml?

Below is an example of what I am talking about.

```
def show
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render :xml => @person }
  end
end
```

produces the following xml

```
<person>
  <name>Paul</name>
  <age>25</age>
  <phone>555.555.5555</phone>
</person>
```

However, I do not want the phone property to be shown. Is there some parameter in the render method that excludes properties from being rendered in xml? Kind of like the following example

```
def show
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render :xml => @person, :exclude_attribute => :phone }
  end
end
```

which would render the following xml

```
<person>
  <name>Paul</name>
  <age>25</age>
</person>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass an array of model attribute names to the `:only` and `:except` options, so for your example it would be:

```
def show
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render :text => @person.to_xml, :except => [:phone] }
  end
end
```

- [to_xml documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001145)

Answer (score 7):

I just was wondering this same thing, I made the change at the model level so I wouldn't have to do it in the controller, just another option if you are interested.

**model**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 def to_xml
  super(:except => [:phone])
 end
 def to_json
  super(:except => [:phone])
 end
end
```

**controller**

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  # GET /people
  # GET /people.xml
  def index
    @people = Person.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @people }
      format.json  { render :json => @people }
    end
  end
end
```

I set one of them up for json and xml on every object, kinda convenient when I want to filter things out of every alternative formatted response.  The cool thing about this method is that even when you get a collection back, it will call this method and return the filtered results.

Answer (score 2):

The "render :xml" did not work, but the to_xml did work. Below is an example

```
def show
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render :text => @person.to_xml(:except => [:phone]) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The except is good, but you have to remember to put it everywhere.  If you're putting this in a controller, every method needs to have an except clause.  I overwrite the serializable_hash method in my models to exclude what I don't want to show up.  This has the benefits of not having t put it every place you're going to return as well as also applying to JSON responses.